# some questions in Collection.add and Collection.addAll

Tags: java, generics

```
boolean addAll(Collection<? extends E> c);
boolean add(E e);
```

The param in Collection.addAll is `Collection<? extends E>`,I think it means all subclass of E can be use, but the param in Collection.add is E. I think it means only E class can be use.

So why the subclass of E can not be param in this method? Such as `<T extends E> boolean add(T t);`

Comment: Anything that extends E is also an E. But, as generics are invariant, the same principle does not apply.

Comment: @bcsb1001 where invariance means that a `Collection<SubclassOfE>` is not a `Collection<E>`. See https://stackoverflow.com/q/2745265/3788176. (Provided for OP's benefit, not yours; it just follows from your comment :) )

Answer (score 2):

The upper bound wildcard is necessary for a Collection of type T. Let's take the following structure

```
class Animals{}
class Dog extends Animals{}
class Cat extends Animals{}

class Container<T>{
    void add(T t){};
    void addAll(Collection<T> t){};
}
```

And we instantiate it and use it like this

```
ArrayList<Dog> dogs = new ArrayList<>();
dogs.add(new Dog());

ArrayList<Cat> cats = new ArrayList<>();
cats.add(new Cat());

Container<Animals> animalContainer = new Container<>();
animalContainer.add(dogs.get(0)); // will work since add(T t)
animalContainer.addAll(cats); // will not work since addAll(Collection<T> t)
```

The reason why it will not work with `addAll(Collection<T> t)` is that the container will only accept the type `T` which is `Animal`, but since the cat list is of type `Cat` it violates the constraints.

Since `Animal` can be a `Dog`, `Cat`, `AnyOtherConcreteAnimal`. By changing it to an upper bound wildcard

```
void addAll(Collection<? extends T> t){};
```

You say that you expect an Collection with the concrete type of `Animals` and not **only** `T` which is `Container<Animals>`. And now this will work again

```
 animalContainer.addAll(cats); // will work since addAll(Collection<? extends T> t)
```

Comment: Why Animals can be Dog in `animalContainer.add(dogs.get(0));`?

Comment: @sibo.wang Look here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2745265/is-listdog-a-subclass-of-listanimal-why-arent-javas-generics-implicitly-p

Comment: Sorry, I don't think those answers can deal my question.

Comment: @sibo.wang It is exactly your question you are asking.